# Power Apps Canvas App - Show Fields from Lookup Record that is not the Lookup field in ComboBox

Tags: list, sharepoint, combobox, powerapps

I have two sharepoint lists:

SiteSurvey

- Title
- RoomName
- RoomNumber
- RoomType

RoomPhotos

- Title
- Room (This is a lookup field to 'ID' of a Record in the 'SiteSurvey' List)
- PhotoNotes
- Photo

I want to have a combo box show the 'RoomName' field so a selection can select the room based on room name even though the 'ID' field in the 'SiteSurvey' list is the lookup field.  I can only get the 'ID' field to populate in the combobox.

For those familiar with Microsoft Access, what I want to do is easily accomplished using the Column widths and bound column properties of a combo box where the bound field is not visible and the record's other desired fields are visible in the combobox.  I'm not understanding something with these comboboxes in Power Apps.

Comment: have you checked the 'Fields' property of the combobox? It allows you to choose fields and layout. You can then reference the selected item as a record and use it's ID property under the hood.

Comment: Hi mmikesy90, I have been using the "Fields" property in the first tab of the combobox properties, but it is just showing 'Value".  I ended up changing the lookup field from ID to Title in order to get the combobox to have a suitable value.  I would love to learn how these comboboxes really work though.